# How to delay Docker Swarm updating a stateful container until it's ready?

Tags: docker, continuous-deployment

**Problem domain**

Imagine that a stateful container is being managed by Swarm, e.g. a database, and another container is relying on it, e.g. a service that is executing a long-running job (minutes, sometimes hours) that does not tolerate the database (or even itself) to go down while it's executing.

To give an example, a database importing a multi GB dump.

There's also a CI/CD system in place which takes care of building new versions of the containers and deploying them to the Swarm, or pushing the image to Docker Hub which then calls a defined webhook which fires off the deployment event.

**Question**

Is there any way I can build my containers so that Swarm can know whether it's ok to update it or not? Similarly how `HEALTHCHECK` reports whether it needs to be restarted, something that would let Swarm know that 'It's safe to restart this container now'.

Or is it the CI/CD system's responsibility to check whether the stateful containers are safe to restart, and only then issue the update command to swarm?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker will not check with a container if it is ready to be stopped, once you give docker the command to stop a container it will perform that action. However it performs the stop in two steps. The first step is a `SIGTERM` that your container can trap and gracefully handle. By default, after 10 seconds, a `SIGKILL` is sent that the Linux kernel immediately applies and cannot be trapped by the container. For your goals, you'll want to make sure your app knows when it's safe to exit after receiving the first signal, and you'll probably want to extend the time to much longer than 10 seconds between signals.

The healthcheck won't tell docker that your container is at a safe point to stop. It does tell swarm when your container has finished starting, or when it's misbehaving and needs to be stopped and replaced. The healthcheck defines a command to run inside your container, and the exit code is checked for whether it's 0 (healthy) or 1 (unhealthy). No other exit codes are currently valid.

If you need more than the simple signal handling inside the container, then yes, you're likely moving up the stack to a ci/cd tool to manage the deployment.